# Hello world на node.js

Tags: node.js

Приведу пример Hello world функции на другом языке:

```
public void hello(string arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello" + arg);
}
```

Как такую же функцию реализовать на node.js?

Comment: точно также, просто убрав типы переменных и заменив Console.WriteLine на console.log

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я знаю, что ответ уже дал [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy), но вот мой вариант.

Если вы хотите сделать функцию:

```
function hello(arg){ // Определить функцию
    console.log("Hello" + arg); // Напечатать в консоль
}
hello() // Вызвать функцию
```

Если вы хотите **Hello `(name)`**:

```
var name = "bob"
console.log("Hello " + name)
```